# CAML query filtering where clause

Tags: powershell, caml

I have the following caml within powershell. If I hardcode the $month in the CAML Query then it works. Is the syntax I am using proper?

```
write-host $month
$CAML = '<Where>
         <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name="Period" />
            <Value Type="Text">$month</Value>
         </Eq>
        </Where>'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PowerShell, strings are either *expandable* (like interpolatable strings in perl), or *literal*.

Anything enclosed in double-quotes (`"`) is expandable, whereas single-quotes (`'`) are used for string literals, as in your case.

```
$month = 'Jan'
"First month is $month" # This will result in: First month is Jan
'First month is $month' # This will result in: First month is $month
```

For multi-line strings, use a here-string (usually called here-docs in other languages). Same rules apply:

```
$CAML = @"
<Where>
  <Eq>
    <FieldRef Name="Period" />
    <Value Type="Text">$month</Value>
  </Eq>
</Where>
"@
```

If you want to use a string literal (ie. if the string contains other special characters or literal `$`s that you want to preserve) but you need to insert a specific variable value, use the `-f` format operator [as shown by @jisaak](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36988361/712649):

```
$CAML = @'
<Where>
  <Eq>
    <FieldRef Name="Period" />
    <Value Type="Text">{0}</Value>
  </Eq>
</Where>
'@ -f $month
```

---

To learn more about string expansion and quoting, please see [`Get-Help about_Quoting_Rules`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847740.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Your variable don't get replaced because you are using single quotes. You can either, use double quotes, or a format string (alias `-f`):

```
write-host $month
$CAML = '<Where>
         <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name="Period" />
            <Value Type="Text">{0}</Value>
         </Eq>
        </Where>' -f $month
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick fix. It's works. However, I just learn following code will work as well. $CAML = "<Where>
    <Eq>
    <FieldRef Name='Period' />
    <Value Type='Text'>$($month)</Value>
    </Eq>
   </Where>"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jissak. Just wanted to share following code as this one works too.

```
$CAML = "<Where>
             <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name='Period' />
                <Value Type='Text'>$($month)</Value>
             </Eq>
            </Where>"
```

Comment: In your case, it will work without the subexpression operator (`$()`) as well.